# drop function cause KeyError on dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In the testColumn function (see full code), when I delete a column in a dataframe with `drop` it throws me a keyerror which I don't understand

after having done drop I can display my dataframe, the drop function works but causes an error in the following

```
#...in testColumn ----
xtrain = X_train.drop([c], axis=1)
xtest = X_test.drop([c], axis=1)
#...
```

however if I write this I have no error:

```
#...in testColumn ---
xtrain = X_train
xtest = X_test
#...
```

why?

```py
import pandas as pd

def euclidian_distance(v1, v2):
    distance = 0
    for i in range(v1.shape[0]):
        distance += (v1[i] - v2[i]) ** 2
    return np.sqrt(distance)


def neighbors(X_train, y_label, x_test, k):
    list_distances = []

    for i in range(X_train.shape[0]):
        distance = euclidian_distance(X_train.iloc[i], x_test)

        list_distances.append(distance)

    df = pd.DataFrame()

    df["label"] = y_label
    df["distance"] = list_distances

    df = df.sort_values(by="distance")

    return df.iloc[:k, :]


def prediction(neighbors):
    return neighbors['label'].mode()

def testColumn(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, k):
    les_taux = []
    for c in range(X_train.shape[1]):
        xtrain = X_train.drop([c], axis=1)
        xtest = X_test.drop([c], axis=1)
        print(xtrain)
        succes = 0
        for i in range(xtest.shape[0]):
            res = prediction(neighbors(xtrain, Y_train, xtest.iloc[8], k))
            if res == Y_test.iloc[i]:
                succes += 1
        taux_succes = (succes / xtest.shape[0])
        les_taux.append(taux_succes)
    return les_taux
```

** Error output: **

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1625, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1632, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/knn.py", line 123, in <module>
    les_taux, c = testColumn(Xt_train, Yt_train, Xt_test, Yt_test, 1)
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/knn.py", line 83, in testColumn
    res = prediction(neighbors(xtrain, Y_train, xtest.iloc[8], k))
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/knn.py", line 35, in neighbors
    distance = euclidian_distance(X_train.iloc[i], x_test)
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/knn.py", line 20, in euclidian_distance
    distance += (v1[i] - v2[i]) ** 2
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 853, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 961, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

**UPADATE**
j'ai mis la fonction à jour comme ceci :

```
def testColumn(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, k):
    les_taux = []
    for c in X_train.columns:
        xtrain = X_train.drop([c], axis=1)
        xtest = X_test.drop([c], axis=1)
        print(xtrain)#works
        print(xtest)#works
        succes = 0
        for i in range(xtest.shape[0]):
            res = prediction(neighbors(xtrain, Y_train, xtest.iloc[i], k))
            if res == Y_test.iloc[i]:
                succes += 1
        taux_succes = (succes / xtest.shape[0])
        les_taux.append(taux_succes)
    return les_taux
```

To check that drop works well I made a display directly after the deletion of the dataframe columns which is done correctly, however when I remove
the rows to delete the columns it work.

**The new error output** (which appears to be the same as above):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1625, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1632, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/knn.py", line 123, in <module>
    les_taux = testColumn(Xt_train, Yt_train, Xt_test, Yt_test, 1)
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/knn.py", line 83, in testColumn
    res = prediction(neighbors(xtrain, Y_train, xtest.iloc[i], k))
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/knn.py", line 35, in neighbors
    distance = euclidian_distance(X_train.iloc[i], x_test)
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/knn.py", line 20, in euclidian_distance
    distance += (v1[i] - v2[i]) ** 2
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 853, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 961, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "/home/etudiant/phython/CompetitionMachineLearning/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Because `drop` drops based on **label names** and you don't have a column **named** `0`. You can insead: `X_train.drop(X_train.columns[c], axis=1)` since `c` seems to be an array position index.

Comment: it always gives me the same error :(

Comment: `add columns=['c'] instead of [c]`
`xtrain = X_train.drop(columns = ['c'], axis=1) `